# How to display min and max pixel from Zonal Statistics?

Tags: qgis, zonal-statistics

I am trying to find the maximum and minimum pixel from a raster inside the area of a buffer. I can succesfully get the values using Zonal Statistics, but it doesnt tell me which pixel is the max and min and I would like to determine that in order to be able to display it in the map.

I am using QGIS 2.18.16